How can I override a function of a class that is inheriting another class that calls on a global function?
I am trying to override a function from a class that inherits from another class, where the parent class is calling on a global function.
I believe I would need to move the function within the class and override, but even if I do that I am not sure how I can override it with the existing code.
Here is my code:
@dataclasses.dataclass
class ConsolidatedDailyParsingDefinitionByMic(DailyProcessingParameters):

    def DAG(self):
        ...
        with DAG(dag_name, default_args=args, ...) as dag:

            for task_group_config in self.task_group_list:
                task_group_instance = DailyParsingTaskDefinition(**task_group_config)
                task_group_instance.parsing_tasks() <---- trying to override a functio in here

     def count_identities_stage(dag_def):
         ########## I am trying to get this function to be called!!#############


@dataclasses.dataclass
class DailyParsingTaskDefinition(DailyDownloadDefinition):
    def parsing_tasks(self):
        self.count_identities = count_identities_stage(self)


def count_identities_stage(dag_def):
    ....
    return count_identities

What I am trying to do is to override count_identities_stage, so that when it is called in the class ConsolidatedDailyParsingDefinitionByMic, it calls on the count_identities_stage function that is defined inside of the class, and not the global one.

If you're in control of where def count_identities_stage(dag_def): is defined, you could make it trampoline:
def count_identities_stage(dag_def):
    if hasattr(dag_def, "count_identities_stage"):
        return dag_def.count_identities_stage()
    return count_identities

If you're not in control, you could use e.g. unittest.mock.patch to patch in a trampoline implementation like that in the namespace where DailyParsingTaskDefinition imports count_identities_stage.

Great idea, but inside the function dag_def doesn't have count_identities_stage attribute.

Ah, so then you can just patch this for the duration of the task_group_instance.parsing_tasks() call, and hard-code it to self.count_identities_stage() (where self is ConsolidatedDailyParsingDefinitionByMic).
